# Batik: IllegalStateException when I call invokeLater from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, illegalstateexception, batik

I already posted a similar question here: [Batik IllegalStateException when resizing the JComponent containing the JSVGCanvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601027/batik-illegalstateexception-when-resizing-the-jcomponent-containing-the-jsvgcanv). I could however reduce the problem to a minimal set of code. Maybe that helps someone to find my problem.

I am calling the following code from a Thread repeatedly:

```
//currentComponent is a custom JComponent that contains the JSVGCanvas
if(currentComponent != null && currentComponent.getSvgCanvas().getUpdateManager() != null)
{
    try
    {
        currentComponent.getSvgCanvas().getUpdateManager().getUpdateRunnableQueue().invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                resetDocument();
            }

            private void resetDocument()
            {
                currentComponent.getSvgCanvas().setDocument(currentComponent.getSvgCanvas().getSVGDocument());
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sometimes I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RunnableQueue not started or has exited
    at org.apache.batik.util.RunnableQueue.invokeLater(RunnableQueue.java:277)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is this a bug in Batik or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had simmilar problem.Same IllegalStateException occured only in special usecases.

My problem was that my code was executed during

```
documentLoadingCompleted(SVGDocumentLoaderEvent P_event)
```

since I'm executing my code during

```
gvtRenderingCompleted(GVTTreeRendererEvent P_e)
```

everything works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It works now with a similar solution. As you said the trick is to run the code during gvtRenderingCompleted. I did not realize that the JSVGCanvas gets a new UpdateManager when you call setDocument(). But now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/util/RunnableQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29

```
  public void invokeLater(Runnable r)

  Schedules the given Runnable object for a later invocation, and returns. An exception is thrown if the RunnableQueue was not started. 
  Throws:
    IllegalStateException - if getThread() is null.
```

It looks as though your RunnableQueue hasn't been started...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have seen that, the exception is thrown when the thread reference is set to null, which happens at the end of the run() method of Batik's RunnableQueue. Most of the time this works, but sometimes the queue does not seem to have started. Is there a way of synchronizing that?